# Property of signed measure and total variation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, total-variation

Let $\nu$ be a signed measure on $(X,\mathcal{M})$. The total variation of $\nu$ is defined as

$$
|\nu|= \nu^+ + \nu^-,
$$

where $\nu = \nu^+ - \nu^-$ is the Jordan decomposition of $\nu$.

For every $B \in \mathcal{M}$, one can show that if $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then

$$
|\nu(B)| = \sup \left(\int_Bfd|\nu|:f \text{ is measurable, } |f| \leq 1 \right).
$$

**Question:**

How can I show that

$$
|\nu(B)| = \sup \left(\int_Bfd\nu:f \text{ is measurable, } |f| \leq 1 \right).
$$

That is, the equality still holds with $\nu$ instead of $|\nu|$ in the integral?

Comment: $\nu_+$ lives on $P$ and $\nu_-$ on $N$. Then simply multiply $f$ by the appropriate indicator functions

Comment: Just to add to @Andrew 's answer, the indicator function will be measurable because $P$ and $N$ are measurable, so therefore also the product.